# Working with MySQL control structures from C++

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I suppose that I **work with** these **MySQL control structures** (see below) in absolutely wrong way. The problem is maybe in MySQL query, but I am not sure...

> MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'IF @records > 1000 THEN SELECT @actRecords:=COUNT(id) FROM
>   `sys_proc_err` WHERE ' at line 1

```
#include <mysql.h>
// other includes, declarations for mysql... etc.

int main() {
  mysql_init(&mysql);
  mysql_real_connect(&mysql,DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DB_IN,0,0,CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS);

  // Now: DELETE ERROR RECORDS older than 3 days if there is more than 1 000 records, leave 1 000 newest records
  mysql_query(connection, "SELECT @records:=COUNT(`id`) FROM `sys_proc_err`;
    IF @records > 1000 THEN SELECT @actRecords:=COUNT(`id`) FROM `sys_proc_err` WHERE time > (NOW()-259200);
    END IF;
    IF @actRecords > 1000 THEN DELETE FROM `sys_proc_err` WHERE `time` < (NOW()-259200);
    ELSE DELETE FROM `sys_proc_err` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT @actRecords-1,@records-@actRecords;
    END IF;");

  return 0;
}
```

Result for `SELECT @records:=COUNT(id) FROM sys_proc_err` is 1267.

Result for `SELECT @actRecords:=COUNT(id) FROM sys_proc_err WHERE time > (NOW()-259200)` is 6.

Comment: You need to submit a single query, and your MySql syntax is wrong: `THEN` instead of `THAN`.

Comment: @drdwilcox Okay, I've edited the code, but it still not works.

Comment: maybe you should include the code where you connect to the Db. There could be a problem there

Comment: @xbonez No, that's not my problem. Connection is fine. I've added MySQL Error to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout multi-statements and multi-queries, multi-results connection options to be passed to mysql_real_connect.

Docs are here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-options.html

Comment: I've enabled multi-statements, but MySQL error is still the same.

Comment: You cannot use an IF like that from the mysql client afaik. Can you turn your code into a StoredProcedure?

Comment: Yes, StoredProcedure is great solution! Thanks.